# The fourth root of (12) or any other number in Python 3

Tags: python, math, python-3.x, nth-root

I'm trying to make a simple code for power 12 to 4(12 ** 4) .
I have the output num (20736) but when I want to figure returns (20736) to its original value (12). I don't know how to do that in Python ..
in Real mathematics I do that by the math phrase {12؇}

The question is how to make {12؇} in Python ??
I'm using sqrt() but sqrt only for power 2

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python3.3
import math 
def pwo():
   f=12 ** 4 #f =20736 #
   c=        # should  c = 12 #
   return f,c
print pwo()
```

Comment: `20736 ** 0.25` might be a bit off, or exact, I don't know for sure. The `n`-th root of `x` is `x^(1/n)`, so `20736 ** (1.0/4)`.

Comment: Hint: `n^(1/4) = (n^(1/2))^(1/2)`. Or use `n ** 0.25`.

Comment: In math, `12؇4` is the 12th root of 4, not the 4th root of 12. In other words, it's the inverse of `4 ** 12`, not the inverse of `12 ** 4`. Which one do you actually want?

Comment: @DanielFischer: And if you want it exact to a given number of decimal places, just use `20736 ** decimal.Decimal(1)/4` instead.

Comment: @abarnert :12؇ is the 4th root of 12 ; 12*12*12*12=20736 :(20736؇4=12)

Comment: Apparently my font doesn't display U+0607 (؇) usefully, so I guessed wrong at what you meant. It's supposed to be the traditional Arabic fourth-root symbol, equivalent to the western U+221C (∜), not the xth-root symbol.

Comment: the symbol ∜ from Western Arabic numerals :(1234567890) and ؇ for Eastern Arabic numerals :(٠‎ ١‎ ٢‎ ٣‎ ٤‎ ٥‎ ٦‎ ٧‎ ٨‎ ٩‎) Thank U a lot ;Im from saudi arabia

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For scientific purposes (where you need a high level of precision), you can use numpy:

```
>>> def root(n, r=4):
...     from numpy import roots
...     return roots([1]+[0]*(r-1)+[-n])
...
>>> print(root(12))
[ -1.86120972e+00+0.j          -3.05311332e-16+1.86120972j
  -3.05311332e-16-1.86120972j   1.86120972e+00+0.j        ]
>>>
```

The output may look strange, but it can be used just as you would use a list.  Furthermore, the above function will allow you to find any root of any number (I put the default for r equal to 4 since you asked for the fourth root specifically).  Finally, numpy is a good choice because it will return the complex numbers that will also satisfy your equations.

Comment: So, it seems this may not be quite as precise as a simpler Python method for finding the first non-imaginary positive root in some cases. E.g.: (Sorry, oneliners…) `import numpy as np`, `numpy_root = lambda n, r: float(np.real(filter(lambda n: np.imag(n) == 0 and n > 0, np.roots(np.double([1]+[0]*(r-1)+[-n])))[0]))`, `py_root = lambda n, r: float(n)**(1.0/float(r))`. On my box, `numpy_root(2, 12) == 1.0594630943592955`, but `py_root(2, 12) == 1.0594630943592953`, which is better according to http://www.komsta.net/digits/12roots/ . Am I doing something bad? Would another numpy API be better…?

Answer (score 24):

```
def f(num):
    return num**0.25
```

or

```
import math
def f(num):
    return math.sqrt(math.sqrt(num))
```

Comment: +1 Yup. Sometimes the simplest solution is to think in terms of Math, before touching the keyboard ;)

Comment: For future reference:

Square root: num ** (1 / 2)

Cube Root: num ** (1 / 3)

nth root: num ** (1 / n)